# remove html background-image when not wanted

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I currently use the following code to put a background on the whole html document, but I only want it on the main home page - once a user login I want it to be removed is there away with CSS or Javascript to do such a thing?

```
html{display:block;
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
    background: url("../images/carged_dog.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;}
  html,body{    margin:0;   padding:0;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional css class for the logged in state for example

```
<html class="user-logged-in">
```

and add the following CSS

```
html.user-logged-in {
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it.

#### Server side code

I'm an ASP.NET dev so, I would provide that code, you can use the Alternate of this in your own language

```
if(WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
   <div class="body-no-background">
      // content
   </div>
}
```

Then in the Class, apply no background.

However, JavaScript cannot detect any user logged in or not. But, you can create a variable and give it a value. Then you can use that value, like this

```
if(!userLogged) { // userLogged is a boolean type, with true false value
   document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage = "";
}
```

In JavaScript you would require a condition to check whether user was logged in or not, that would be using Server Side language. Give a value to some hidden input field.

In CSS, you cannot do that. You would require to use a seperate class, for seperate conditions. Otherwise, you cannot detect such thing using CSS. CSS is not designed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to —in the HTML— put a class on the `<html>` tag on the home page in, e.g., `<html class=home-page>`. Then, in css you would have a selector that only puts the background image on the `.home-page` class, like so:

```
html {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}   
html.home-page { 
  background: url("../images/carged_dog.jpg") center center / cover no-repeat fixed; 
}
```

Also, some other notes, unless you need to support older browsers, vendor prefixes are not needed on the [background-size property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). You can also combine the property with the background property using a forward slash like I have. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) for more.